# nomenclature question: nonconvex functions with only saddle points and global minima

Tags: functions, numerical-optimization

Is there a categorical term used to describe all nonconvex functions whose critical points are only saddle points and global minima? I am working on a nonlinear structured matrix factorization problem with these properties and would like to learn more about the general properties of such functions. From what I understand, any quasiconvex function would fall under this description but not all functions with these properties are quasiconvex since $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \leq \max \{f(x),f(y)\}$ for $\lambda \in [0,1]$ is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 1):

Since a critical point is either a local minimum, a local maximum or a saddle point, these are just the functions with no local maximum and no non-global local minima.  Any differentiable function falls into this class if you restrict the domain to exclude any local maxima and non-global local minima.  So I doubt that you'll get very much in the way of properties.

Comment: One could also say that any differentiable function is convex if you restrict the domain around a local minimum (if one exists), no? In any case, I agree with you that this category probably is too broad for there to be much in terms of general properties apart from the fact that a globally optimal solution can be found numerically using deterministic methods (such as regularizing the Hessian with the identity matrix to maintain positive definiteness).

Comment: Numerical methods might not find a globally optimal solution, if the global optimum is on the boundary of the domain.

Comment: Excuse my potential ignorance, but aren't modern nonlinear, nonconvex interior point methods quite reliable for finding minima/maxima on boundaries (and designed to do so e.g. Numerical Optimization by Nocedal & Wright)? At least in my limited anecdotal experience using IP methods, they find local minima that lie on the boundary. If you mean specifically global optima, I would agree as global optimality is not guaranteed unless all local optima are global optima and the domain can be expressed by equality and inequality constraints that are linear and convex, respectively.